# Mysql/PHP get post.userid from a column with the row selected by post.postid

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mamp

I am using Dreamweaver and MAMP to create a site. I have a table called posts inside I have two columns, postid, and userid. I'm putting all the posts on a page and I want to show which user posted which post, and write that on each post respectively. For example the first post that should show up has a postid of 2 and a userid of 1.
Currently it is displaying the userid of the user who is logged in on all the posts, I am using:

```
mysql_select_db($database_akaearthdb, $akaearthdb);
$query_PostsUserid = "SELECT userid FROM posts WHERE posts.userid ORDER BY posts.postid";
$row_PostsUserid = mysql_fetch_assoc($PostsUserid);
```

and

```
echo $row_PostsUserid['userid']
```

To display it. I want $row_PostsUserid['userid'] to be the userid of the person who posted it.

Let me know if you need any more information, I'm new to the language so sorry if I'm doing everything wrong, TIA.

Comment: Why are you fetching from this $PostsUserId variable and not $query_PostsUserid?

Comment: @Overv I didn't hand code it I used dreamweaver's tools. I changed the 'echo $row_PostsUserid['userid']' to 'echo $query_PostsUserid['userid']' and now it just puts "S" on every post instead of "1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before executing a query from any language,

**Test the query on your local database command line.**

Your query,

```
"SELECT userid FROM posts WHERE posts.userid ORDER BY posts.postid"
```

will result in a syntax error.

### EDIT:

Do the following,

```
CREATE TABLE users (
         id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
         user_name VARCHAR(255),
         age INT,
         any_detail VARCHAR(255)
       );

CREATE TABLE posts (
         id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
         post TEXT,
         created_at TIMESTAMP(8),
         user_id INT,
         FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
       );
```

Now,

To display the posts,

```
Array =  SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

*Store the result from the above query into your languages array/variable. Im a rails developer, Im not sure about PHP's syntax.(Google it and find out!)*

After storing the results into an array,

Display the following for each element in the array as follows,

**Post content:

<< Array.post >>

Written about:

<< Array.created_at >> ago

Written by:

<< SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_id = Array.user_id >>**

That should help or take you somewhere.

Comment: (The WHERE was an accident left over from something else) I want to display all the posts with their information as well as the user who posted it, I have a user and a post table and a foreign key of userid on every post currently it is just displaying 1 as the userid for all the posts

Comment: This seems like it would work but I can't figure out how to do the **= Array.user_id** part, I'm not sure how to save the result as an array that can be used by another query. Let me know if you figure out a way, I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something on your 'WHERE' clause:

WHERE posts.userid [ = something ]

That will be the first step towards getting the data you want from your DB.

Comment: I doubt he even wants that WHERE to be there in the first place. I don't see what function it should have.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that I was trying some other stuff and forgot to remove the WHERE.

Comment: Can you supply the design for all the tables you're working with?

Comment: @charliep I have 4 tables for the site currently, the two I'm working with for this site are, `posts` and `users`. `posts` has information about each post such as title content etc. and a foreign key of `userid`. The `users` table has information about each user, such as their username. With each post I can display the `posts.userid` values like 1,2,3. What I want to do is take those and find the `users.userid` that fits then find the username of that user and display that.